# Urban Airship Push code

Tags: java, post, urbanairship.com

I've followed the UA tutorials and got my APID , and successfully recieved test push message on my android device.

Now the next thing that I like to do is to target my device using JAVA and send push messaged.
From what I've seen so far the best way to achieve this is using their web API.

However When I'm trying to send a post message I always get the following error :

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at com.Sender.Sender.main(Sender.java:56)

This is the code that I use :

```
package com.Sender;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Sender {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String responseString = "";
        String outputString = "";
        String username = "MWMoRVhmRXOG6IrvhMm-BA";
        String password = "ebsJS2iXR5aMJcOKe4rCcA";

        MyAuthenticator ma= new MyAuthenticator(username, password);

        Authenticator.setDefault(ma);

        URL url = new URL("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String APID = "23eef280-19c8-40fc-b798-788f50e255a2";

        String postdata = "{\"android\": {\"alert\": \"Hello from JAVA!\"}, \"apids\": [\""+APID+"\"]}";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[postdata.length()];
        buffer = postdata.getBytes("UTF8");

        bout.write(buffer);
        byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                String.valueOf(b.length));

        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(b);
        out.close();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                httpConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            outputString = outputString + responseString;
        }
        System.out.println(outputString);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401 represent Unauthorized access. In your code even though your created Authenticator, you didn't provide it as part of post request header. Here is tutorial on how to set [authenticator](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip47.html) for a URLConnection.

Comment: Thanks For your reply . But what about the line " Authenticator.setDefault(ma);" . I thought it takes care of everything. Otherwise How shall I attach the Authenticator as a part of the header ?

Comment: I dont think setDefaul is enough. In the link I posted in my answer has how to set Authenticator as part of header.

Comment: Ok , I followed the guide and now I'm getting 400 Error . Here is my new code and Error description below http://pastie.org/3281240